# Google One Tap sign-in to control Drive

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, google-one-tap

In my Android application I was able to log in using the Google One Tap sign-in (https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap), obtaining a token ID. Could anyone tell me if I can use this token to manage Google Drive? Perhaps through the Java Drive API (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java) with https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Those base64 [credentials](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/credentials/Credential?hl=en) identify the user. You could use that data to print the user's full name in your navigation bar, per example. If you want to perform some API actions with that user, you are going to need prompting the user for consent. Please check this [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app) to learn more about the authorization flow. That guide that you shared, the Drive API Java Quickstart, is a good place to start developing your webapp.